# Flask Jinja2 template reload generated table on button click

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask, jinja2

I have an app running through flask which will be used for automated provisioning of servers on my cloud platform.

One of the pages lets you upload a spreadsheet, which then gets parsed into an interactive (editable) html `<table>`.

Upon populating the table, the populated fields are validated. If any fields are invalid, the field's class changes to highlight where the end user would need to edit.

There is then a validator button which takes the current html table and runs validation on it again, which works fine. However it doesn't reload the html table, so any fields that were invalid that have been changed by the user remain highlighted due to the class not changing.

What do I need to change here to ensure the table gets refreshed?

Here's the code.

#### Flask:

```
# upload spreadsheet and validate
@app.route('/upload/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload():
    # if a file is attempted to be uploaded, save file and parse it
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.files:
        f = request.files['file']
        f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], secure_filename(f.filename)))
        myexcel = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], f.filename)
        myJson = exc.Parse(myexcel)
        mySpreadsheet = spreadsheet.zip_list(myJson)
        return render_template('upload2.html', spreadsheet=mySpreadsheet)
    # if the validate button is clicked, validate and repopulate table:
    elif request.method == 'POST' and not request.files:
        data = request.get_json()
        data = json.loads(str(data['rows']).replace("'",'"'))
# Test print. this prints the data as expected on click of the validate button
        pprint(data) 
        mySpreadsheet = spreadsheet.zip_list(data)
        return render_template('upload2.html', spreadsheet=mySpreadsheet)
    else:
        return render_template('upload2.html')
```

#### HTML table:

(yes it's a massive table!)

```
<!-- bunch of table headers here -->
{% for row in spreadsheet %}
  <tr class="{{ loop.cycle('color1', 'color2') }}">
  {% for i in range(36) %}
    {% if "-invalid" in row[i]|string %}
      <td contenteditable="true" class="red table-editable">{{ row[i]|replace("-invalid", "") }}</td>
    {% else %}
      <td contenteditable="true" class="table-editable">{{ row[i] }}</td>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

#### HTML validate:

```
<div class="container">
  <button id="validate" value="validate" class="button" >Validate Spreadsheet</button>
</div>
```

#### Jquery/AJAX:

```
// on validate, send potentially updated table in json format to flask
$('#validate').click(function() {
var $table = $("table")
    rows = [],
    header = [];
$table.find("thead th").each(function () {
    header.push($.trim($(this).text()));
});
$table.find("tbody tr").each(function () {
    var row = {};
    $(this).find("td").each(function (i) {
        var key = header[i],
            value = $(this).text();
        row[key] = value;
    });
    rows.push(row);
});
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        url: "/upload/",
        traditional: "true",
        data: JSON.stringify({rows}),
        dataType: "json"
    });
});
```

So AJAX sends the data to flask without issue, but when that `elif` statement gets picked up, it doesn't seem to re-render the template with the new data.

Sorry for the long post, and thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as you say it yourself, the whole problem can be summarized in this sentence:

So AJAX sends the data to flask without issue, but when that elif statement gets picked up, it doesn't seem to re-render the template with the new data.

This is because, when you send a POST request, the response by the server is not automatically interpreted. You must do something with the servers response, e.g. render it.

So, you need to add a success parameter to your ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    url: "/upload/",
    traditional: "true",
    data: JSON.stringify({rows}),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response)
        document.open();
        document.write(response);
        document.close();
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, status, err) {
      console.log(jqXHR, status, err);
    }
});
```

Since your server currently responds with a fully rendered html page, you could overwrite the existing content of your page which is shown in the example (bad practice though).

It would be better to make a new route, specifically for validation that everything in the table is correct. You might also consider to solve this problem using `onChange()` in your html td's, and write a javascript function which checks if the input is valid now, to prevent the entire ajax call.

Comment: I've tried your example but it doesn't make any difference unfortunately. Nothing is logged to the console, so I guess it isn't picking up the success? I'm not a web dev myself so sorry if this all sounds silly/obvious. 

I can go the new route method, I was just trying to prevent having to do that. Nice idea with the onChange() thing though. If I didn't hate JS I'd give that a go now. something for the long term though for sure :)

Comment: I've edited to also catch any potential errors in the ajax request, feel free to retry

Comment: thanks! so the error is the json it's trying to parse is invalid apparently.. even though I'm printing that server side and it's valid json..

`parsererror SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"`

the response is the fully rendered html page as expected, can't see anything wrong with that. I'll keep digging away. Thanks for your help

Comment: I changed it to render the response anyway on error to test it, and it sees the returned html as an object. (it literally returns the text `[object Object]`)  which explains the parse error above I guess!

Comment: So the error is occuring on the serverside, because the json you're sending using ajax is not valid. Try changing `data: JSON.stringify({rows}),` to `data: rows,`

Comment: that's what I don't understand; if I print the json AJAX is sending server side, it prints valid json (verified by jsonlint). I did toy with changing to `data: rows,` but that just misses half the html from the response.

Comment: Remove this weird line: `data = json.loads(str(data['rows']).replace("'",'"'))`. Whatever you're trying to do here, don't. Then try again.

Comment: Problem was stupidly simple in the end. datatype needed changing to text since that's what the response was trying to render! 

Thanks for your help @joost